How to isolated a device on the I2C bus?
I have a system with several sensors on the I2C bus that are critical for operation and a humidity sensor which is '(very) nice to have'. Most of the device is pretty waterproof, but the humidity sensor needs to be outside the enclosure for obvious reasons. I'm looking for an IC or method to ensure that the device still works if the humidity sensor is wet. I have included a fuse, but I'm unsure what will happen to the I2C bus, it could feasibly be pulled high or low by a malfunctioning device, either would interfere with all the other sensors and normal operation.
I've been trying to find an IC for this purpose but I've been unable to. Thanks for your help

Welcome! Can you afford to have two separate I2C busses?

Isolate the chip with a resettable I2C mux or just with analog switches. Or use a secondary I2C bus for it - you can have dozens of I2C buses if you bit-bang the non-essential buses on GPIO pins.
If the chip shorts out it might damage the MCU anyway regardless of which pins it uses.

Actually, if the I2C pins on the MCU are properly configured as open-collector and the sensor's supply voltage is the same as the I2C bus voltage, there should be nothing the sensor can do that will damage the MCU.

@DoxyLover Bringing a bus outside an enclosure can get zapped by ESD. Or a cable may break by shorting IOs to VCC. External buses need special care and handling.

Agreed on the ESD but if Vcc is the same voltage as the I2C bus, a short will not kill an open-collector port.
